# How to improve my Dockerfile to create an Docker image for Angular application perfectly?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, azure-devops, devops

I am confused how to create a Dockerfile for any kind of Node.js or Angular application. I made lots of searches to achieve that but I couldn't. I don't understand what it is wrong with my Dockerfile below. How can I improve it?

```
FROM node:12.18-alpine as build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY src/ ./src/



# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN cd src/app && npm install @angular/cli && npm install && npm run build


# # start app
# CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --disableHostCheck true

# generate build
RUN ng build --output-path=dist --configuration=production

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

COPY ./nginx-config.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx-config.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Error after build in Azure pipeline :

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?  (I can't tell from the image, and you should replace the image with the actual text of the error message.)  It seems like there are a lot of different paths in the Dockerfile – `/usr/src`, `/usr/src/src`, `/app` – and it might work better to copy everything into `.`, which will be interpreted as relative to the `WORKDIR`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry for my late response I improved my question. Can you check it again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to improvew my Docker file to create an docker image for angular application perfectly?

I could reproduce this issue via your dockerfile. That because you set the `WORKDIR` to `WORKDIR /usr/src` and copy `package.json` to `/app/package.json`. In this case, the file `package.json` will be copied to the `WORKDIR`, the path should be:

```
/usr/src/app/package.json
```

But, you use the command `RUN cd src/app` in the work folder， which will switch to the path `/usr/src/src/app`. This is different the path from the file exists `/usr/src/app`.

So, to resolve this issue, you need to change the command line:

```
COPY package.json /app/package.json
```

**To:**

```
COPY package.json ./src/app/package.json
```

As test I use `RUN cd src/app && ls` to list the file in the path `/usr/src/src/app`:

[image]